# Sending email containing accent with powershell

Tags: email, powershell, encoding, diacritics

I'm trying to send emails containing accents via powershell.

If i do the following :

```
$enc = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8
Send-MailMessage -to "Recipient@company.com" -from "Sender@company.com" -subject "test" -body "éèà" -Encoding $enc
```

It actually works and i get the accents fine in the mail.

BUT, if i do this :

```
$enc = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8

$Body = @"

éèà

"@

Send-MailMessage -to "Recipient@company.com" -from "Sender@company.com" -subject "test" -body $body -Encoding $enc
```

The email looks like this : Ã©Ã¨Ã

I actually need to use the @" "@ quotes to send multiple lines mails.

Does anybody have a clue of how i could make this work ?

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please try to execute this prior to your script :

```
$OutputEncoding = [Console]::OutputEncoding
```