# Send-mail bad formatting after using out-string

Tags: email, powershell

I have create a function who send with paramaters. The thing when i do a simple write host of the variable who have the main body mail host the formatting is good.

> intervenant: jh
>
> societe: ibm
>
> perimetre d'intervention:IDC 2
>
> auteur de la demande: jh
>
> date d'intervention: aujourd'hui
>
> Cordialement,
>
> Jean-Héder Verdilus.

But after using the command send-mail with string-out, my sending mail look like this ...

> intervenant:
>
> jh
>
> societe:
>
> ibm
>
> perimetre d'intervention:IDC
>
> 2
>
> auteur de la demande:
>
> jh
>
> date d'intervention:
>
> aujourd'hui
>
> Cordialement,
>
> Jean-H?der Verdilus.

It's even worse with parametrer -BodyAsHtml ...

Here the code of the function

function sendmail($nbUser,$subject,$area,$from,$date){

`` # declaration des variable du corps du mail 
 $user = $user
 $companie = $companie
# contiendra tout le corps du mail 
 $body = $body

### ###################boucle qui recupère les informations de l'intervention en fonction du nombre d'intervenant
for ($i=0; $i -le $nbUser-1; $i++){

# ####################récuperation des informations des intervenant
    do{
        $user = Read-Host "entrez le nom et le prenom de l'intervenant"
    }Until ($user -NotLike $NULL -or $user -NotLike "") 

    do{
        $companie = Read-Host "entrez le nom de la société"
     }Until ($companie -NotLike $NULL -or $companie -NotLike "")

################On range ces information dans des tableaux a deux dimensions###################
    $user = @('intervenant:', $user,"`n") 
    $companie = @('societe:', $companie,"`n") 

################on concatène nos tableaux ######################
    $body += $user
    $body += $companie
    $body += @("perimetre d'intervention:IDC",$area,"`n")
    $body += @('auteur de la demande:', $from,"`n")
    $body += @("date d'intervention:", $date,"`n")
    $body += "`n"
    $body += "`n"  
}

########signature##################
$body +='Cordialement,'
$body += "`n"
$body += "Jean-Héder Verdilus."

###on affiche les info du mail a envoyer pour etre sur de l'envoie 
Write-host "voici le mail complet"($subject+"`n"+$to+"`n"+$cc+"`n"+$date+"`n"+" "+$body)

###### demande de confirmation d'envoie du mail#####
do {
   $answer = Read-Host "Voulez vous l'envoyer (yes/no)" } 
until ("yes","no" -ccontains $answer)

##### si oui on envoie si non on quitte####
switch ($answer){
    yes{
    Send-MailMessage -To XXX.XXX.XXX `
    -Subject $subject -From XX.XXX.XXX.X `
    -Body ($body|Out-String)  -SmtpServer XXX.XXX.XXX  -Cc XXX.XXX.XXX 
        }
    no{
    Read-Host -Prompt "Press Enter to exit"
    }
} ``

}

Comment: How/why are you using `Out-String`?

Comment: Because if i don't use out-string i have this error Send-MailMessage : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'Body'. Specified method is not supported.

Comment: Concatenate all the strings in $body before sending: `$body = -join $body`

Comment: it's work ...But i still get a character encoding issue. I have  "Jean-H?der Verdilus" instead of "Jean-Héder Verdilus"

Comment: You should be able to [fix encoding with this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21454096/sending-email-containing-accent-with-powershell)

Comment: Never mind. The is a parameter for encoding in the send-mailmessage fonction. Thanks for your help

Comment: It's work. Thank you so much.